# Remove Overlay on Navigation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I am using `Overlay.of(context)` to display some contents on button click. But there are two problems:

- The overlay is not removed while navigating to next screen.
- Dropdown buttons are used inside it. But the menu items are shown below it.

Here is the 'Expected Output'.
[image: Expected Output]

Current output is in this screenshot.

[image: Current Output]

So, how can the overlay be removed while navigating and the dropdown be shown properly ? If it is not possible with overlay, is there any workaround?

PS: I am using `NavigatorKey` to change tables when names in the fixed sidebar are clicked as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problems.

- The `Overlay` is removed while navigating by using `RouteAware` + `RouteObserver` as shown in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57255437/5992292).
- For dropdown items rendered below the overlay, there is a [fork of default dropdown button](https://gist.github.com/DhytoDev/cdadf2e78bd694192c65b5634c2ad53e) which pushes dropdown items' overlay into `root navigator` instead of nested navigator, and displays them on the top.

Comment: Thanks for that linked answer, it was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent shared any code I can only imagine how you designed your UI. If you share the code in a Dartpad may be some of us can help.

1. `OverlayEntry` can be removed using the `remove`method as per the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry/remove.html). You can do this when you are handling the click on the left menu.
2. For the second problem I couldn't find any working solution. I doubt this is not possible because `Overlay` is a `Stack` widget which is on top of all pages as per the docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html). If you look into the `DropDownButton` code it internally uses `Navigator` to push a new page route as shown 
   [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/0b8abb4724/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L1167) which is still below the Overlay stack and hence I suspect you can achieve this.

That said, you should probably not use `Overlay` for this purpose. Instead you are better off to use `showMenu` function from flutter which provides more convenience and will behave as you expected in most cases. Positioning the menu need some hackery with `showMenu` but achievable.

You can also check [flutter_portal](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal) package which has some nice features. But its still in its development phase.

PS: For inspiration you can check my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800528/3043944) especially the *showMenu approach*.

Comment: I tried both `showMenu` and `flutter_portal`. But it seems `showMenu` is for generating menu items, which is not what I am trying. I want to show some input widgets for filtering the table. `flutter_portal` didn't support `DropdownButton`. There were some complicated nested navigator problems. I think I should go for some other ways to show those filters than dealing with overlays.